# Ruby's SecureRandom and the size of n

Tags: ruby, random, prng

I'm looking for 6 random hex characters, and am using Ruby's [`SecureRandom`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/securerandom/1.9.2/SecureRandom.hex)

`SecureRandom.hex(3)` will return 6 hex characters unpacked from 3 bytes of random data.

The question is, will doing `SecureRandom.hex(6)[0,6]` return 6 hex characters that are more random because there were 6 bytes of random data before the unpacking?  For that matter, would `SecureRandom.hex(16)[0,6]` be even more random?

For my application I only need the 6 characters with over 16 million unique values, but I want the chances of colliding with a number that was already picked to be as low as possible.  So will using a larger `n` for the random bytes improve the distribution of the random values over the space or is it unnecessary?

Answer (score 4):

No.  Selecting a six character substring of a larger random hex string will be no more "random" than using one that is generated as a six character string.

The only way to reduce the probability of collisions is to have more unique possible values.

Comment: I would also add that anytime you start doing things like this to be "more random" it is a major code smell in the randomness arena.  If you can not trust the output of your RNG to give you 6 random characters then a subset from 16 will be no more random.